# VHDL: Unable to assign anything to Integer array Output Port

Tags: vhdl

I am unable to assign any value to the output port which is defined as integer array. I am getting output as "UUUUUUU" in behavioral simulation.
I am trying to use 8 bit Integer array as input and sort and output it to another 8 bit integer array.
But the array can be of any length.
I am planning to use counting sort. But here I am unable to get past the basic output array assignment.
What is wrong with the code[Simulation Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRLoh.jpg)

Design Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package sorting_pkg is
    type intarray is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work; 
use work.sorting_pkg.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity HWsort is
generic (
  N : integer:= 10 );
port( 
    inStream : in intarray(0 to N-1);
    outStream : out intarray(0 to N-1)
);
end HWsort;

architecture Behavioral of HWsort is

begin
  outStream <= inStream;
end Behavioral;
```

TestBench Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work; 
use work.sorting_pkg.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity tb_Sort is
--  Port ( );
end tb_Sort;

architecture Behavioral of tb_Sort is
component HWsort
    PORT
        (
        inStream : in intarray(0 to 9);
        outStream : out intarray(0 to 9));
end component;

signal inStream : intarray(0 to 9);
signal outStream : intarray(0 to 9);

begin
    uut:HWsort port map (inStream => inStream, outStream => outStream);

sim_tb:process
    begin
        wait for 100ns;

        inStream(0 to 9) <= (0 => x"22",
                      1 => x"12",
                      2 => x"1A",
                      3 => x"4A",
                      4 => x"02",
                      5 => x"5B",
                      6 => x"66",
                      7 => x"09",
                      8 => x"35",
                      9 => x"71");
        wait;
        end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Why are there two copies of package sorting_pkg is your code? Both entities use use the same declaration of type intarray, each declaration is unique even if appearing identical. uut is unbound in tb_sort from what you've provided. The component name and instance name match but don't match with HWsort (which also has an integer generic without a default value and no rst port mode in). Provide a [mcve] and any actual warning or error messages during elaboration.

Comment: Instantiating HWSort instead of sorting, analyzing sorting_pkg once, proving a generic value for N, running the process for longer after the assignment to instream and Outstream shows up in a waveform dump. Note rst is not used in HWSort.

Comment: Hey Thanks for pointing out those mistakes and made the changes as suggested by you. You may check the updated code above. But however I am unable to remove the unboundness of the design.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what analysis is required for the packages.

Comment: You'll note @JHBonarius used an entity in component instantiation. Your component declaration doesn't match the entity declartion of HWSort. Add a generic clause to the component declaration. Both the component declaration and entity declaration must match. In addition to the space between the numeric literal and identifier (unit name ns) he mentions, you're not using packages numeric_std, std_logic_unsigned in the tb_Sort in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code, with a small correction of unused packages and a space between `100` and `ns` as required by the standard **edit** and by referring to the entity `HWsort` directly

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package sorting_pkg is
    type intarray is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
end package;

use work.sorting_pkg.all;

entity HWsort is
    generic (
      N : integer:= 10 );
    port( 
        inStream : in intarray(0 to N-1);
        outStream : out intarray(0 to N-1)
    );
end HWsort;

architecture Behavioral of HWsort is begin
    outStream <= inStream;
end Behavioral;

entity tb_Sort is end tb_Sort;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.sorting_pkg.all;

architecture Behavioral of tb_Sort is
    signal inStream : intarray(0 to 9);
    signal outStream : intarray(0 to 9);
begin
    uut: entity work.HWsort port map (inStream => inStream, outStream => outStream);

    sim_tb:process begin
        wait for 100 ns;

        inStream <= (
            0 => x"22",
            1 => x"12",
            2 => x"1A",
            3 => x"4A",
            4 => x"02",
            5 => x"5B",
            6 => x"66",
            7 => x"09",
            8 => x"35",
            9 => x"71");
        wait;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

This is the output after simulating 200 ns:
[image: waveform]

So with regards to your question: there is *nothing* wrong with your code.
**edit** Except the component declaration of `HWsort` differs from the entity, as in: the generic is missing, like user1155120 mentioned.